# Upgrade GCC 4.6.3 on Ubuntu 12.04 to 4.8.2

Tags: gcc, g++, ubuntu-12.04

I'm about to update default GCC (version 4.6.3) shipped by Ubuntu 12.04 to 4.8.2, though the compilation requires a standalone C++ compiler

```
admin@ubuntu: /usr/local/gcc_build$ sudo make
```

ends up with

```
configure: error: C++ compiler missing or inoperational
make[2]: *** [configure-stage1-libcpp] Error 1
```

Therefore I turn to the process of `g++` installation with a preference to the latest version, which means that I would like to compile from source directly rather than `apt-get`. But seriously, I can't find the source anyway!(O_o). On the other hand, does the source of GCC also come along with that of `g++` in the tar file I downloaded, or not? Thanks.

PS: problem remains unsolved with `admin@ubuntu: /usr/local/gcc_build$ /home/admin/gcc-4.8.2/configure --enable-languages=c,c++`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can easily compile the sources.

The following commands worked for gcc 4.7. They should be fine for gcc 4.8 as well:

```
sudo apt-get install libmpfr-dev libgmp3-dev libmpc-dev flex bison

svn checkout svn://gcc.gnu.org/svn/gcc/trunk

cd trunk

./configure --prefix=/opt/gcc-4.8.2/usr/local/gcc-4.8.2 --enable-languages=c,c++

make

make install
```

The compiler will be placed in the */opt/* directory, so you have to use it from there.

Comment: Ok I missed configuration about `--enable-languages`. But are you sure flex and bison are essential?

Comment: Yes, they are (don't know why, but without them the compilation stopped complaining...)

Comment: I assume that without the --prefix flag, gcc will be installed in the appropriate directory, and after make install, "gcc --version" will show 4.8.2?

Comment: @Claudio Thanks, this has been extremely helpful. Only two things: A complaint about a missing `bits/predefs.h` is fixed by `C_INCLUDE_PATH=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/ make` instead of `make`; and a complaint about a missing `gnu/stubs-32.h` is fixed by `sudo apt-get install libc6-dev-i386`.

Comment: @TrevorHickey I did that at the end of November. `gcc --version` showed `4.9.0`. I'm doing it again now, who knows.

Comment: CAUTION: The `make` above failed!

`../.././libcc1/findcomp.cc:20:20: fatal error: config.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.`

Comment: `apt-get build-deps gcc` is better.

Answer (score 11):

1. Add the ppa by

   `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-toolchain-r/test`
2. Install g++ and gcc (version 4.8)

   `sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get install gcc-4.8 g++-4.8`
3. Run the following commands one by one,

   `sudo update-alternatives --remove-all gcc`

   `sudo update-alternatives --remove-all g++`

   `sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/gcc gcc /usr/bin/gcc-4.8 20`

   `sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/g++ g++ /usr/bin/g++-4.8 20`

   `sudo update-alternatives --config gcc`

   `sudo update-alternatives --config g++`

That's it you are done!

Comment: As far I I know, this installed g++ 4.8.1.

Comment: In my case I didn't have any alternatives installed and I wanted to be able to switch back to 4.6 if needed. I had to install the old alternatives with `sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/gcc gcc /usr/bin/gcc-4.6 20` and `sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/g++ g++ /usr/bin/g++-4.6 20`. Now I can use `sudo update-alternatives --config gcc` and `sudo update-alternatives --config g++` to easily change the version any time.

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to compile it yourself ? If not, there is a PPA, described [here](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2013/08/install-gcc-4-8-via-ppa-in-ubuntu-12-04-13-04/)

Comment: They don't have 4.8.2, as requested, yet!

Comment: Worked for me, version is gcc (Ubuntu 4.8.1-2ubuntu1~12.04) 4.8.1