# Install GCC 4.8.2

Tags: ubuntu, gcc

I am trying to install gcc on ubuntu 12.04, 64-bit machine.

I've downloaded their release from: http://gcc.parentingamerica.com/releases/gcc-4.8.2/

Then after I cd to the gcc-4.8.2 folder, I ran the `./configure` as directed from:
[Upgrade GCC 4.6.3 on Ubuntu 12.04 to 4.8.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19836858/upgrade-gcc-4-6-3-on-ubuntu-12-04-to-4-8-2)

But, when I'm trying to run the `make` command, the following message showed up:

> make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.

I'm not sure what steps I missed. Might anyone know the problem?

Comment: Review the `./configure` output. It most likely failed, and didn't produce the `Makefile`.  You're probably missing some [prerequisites](http://gcc.gnu.org/install/prerequisites.html).

Comment: oh, you're right. Thank you very much for pointing that out for me, Jonathon!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Johnathon Reinhart who pointed out that my machine didn't meet the pre-requisite. The problem is solve by installing the following as answered by [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9253695/building-gcc-requires-gmp-4-2-mpfr-2-3-1-and-mpc-0-8-0):

> sudo apt-get install libmpc-dev